# How to format a phone number in java to Android

Tags: java, android, string, libphonenumber

I have a list of phone numbers that I retrieve from an API, and it comes like that: 
(22) 9969-6666 I need to change it so it looks like this: +552299696666

What I tried so far is:

```
                String phoneNum = "(22) 9969-6666 ";
                System.out.println(phoneNum.replaceFirst("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "($1)-$2-$3"));
```

Giving me the following results:

```
10-08 00:23:04.155  30677-30677/br.com I/System.out﹕ (22) (996)-966-66
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not replacing any non-digit character with empty and adding the `+` sign in front of resulting string?

```
String phoneNum = "(22) 9969-6666 ";
phoneNum = "+" + phoneNum.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
System.out.println(phoneNum);
```

Output: +2299696666

Comment: I'm new to java programming language, didn't know how to do that, thank you big time!

Comment: @jgandroid: You're welcome. I just updated the regular expression in the answer, so make sure you get the latest.